# My SGH-i777 running 2.3.4 is saying my firmware is current, but I don't believe it is

Tags: updates

I have a Galaxy S2 SGH-I777 through AT&T. It runs on 2.3.4 Gingerbread and when I try to update my phone says that there are no updates available.

When I try to update through Kies, it says my phone doesn't support initialising. How can I fix this? I want to root my phone but I wanted to update first. Is that smart or should I update after root?

Comment: There's some [discussion here](http://androidforums.com/threads/no-ics-on-sgh-i777.611574/) regarding the Kies error you're getting. Did you get the phone from AT&T or secondhand? Have you ever rooted or modified it before?

Comment: i bought the phone secondhand and yes it was rooted. i am just learning about root and what it can do. im not very knowledgeable when it comes 2 all the technical terms so i will do my best 2 keep up with u. i was hoping this issue didnt have anything 2 do with the phone previously being rooted because that would mean the issue im having is probably my fault. i did root the phone and it worked fine for a week or so and i loved it. then apps started force closing everytime i tried using them, the phone was running slow and my text msgs started going haywire.

Comment: im sure these were all issues caused by something i had done during the time the phone was rooted. i had no choice but 2 unroot the phone and do a factory reset, which i assumed would fix all. i was incorrect huh? also let me tell u that i did try to update b4 i unrooted and it said the same thing its saying now. but this was another reason i felt i should unroot. i thought if i unrooted i would b able to update but i was again mistaken. i would greatly appreciate any advice u could give me. ive googled this topic over and over but u r the 1st live person ive had contact with n this matter.

Comment: i would love to re-root and update the phone but im not sure which order to do it n & idk positively that i havent permanently messed something up. i know ive given u enough 2 think about but one more thing that i want 2 figure out is a wifi issue thats been occuring since the start of the root. i dont expect u 2 tackle all of these issues at once or even at all if u dont want 2 but like i said b4 i definitely need help and id appreciate any advice u can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone has the latest update for its generation. It will receive no more updates for the rest of the time you use it.

In order to "update" your phone, you would have to root it, and then flash a custom rom with an update available for it.